# Why is dhclient sending a DHCPREQUEST before the lease time ends?

Tags: networking, dhcp

```
Jun  9 08:23:11 localhost dhclient[365]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.5.57 on enp4s0 to 192.168.5.254 port 67
Jun  9 08:23:17 localhost dhclient[365]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.5.57 on enp4s0 to 192.168.5.254 port 67
Jun  9 08:23:21 localhost dhclient[365]: DHCPACK of 192.168.5.57 from 192.168.5.254
Jun  9 08:23:21 localhost dhclient[365]: bound to 192.168.5.57 -- renewal in 32796 seconds.
Jun  9 12:10:16 localhost dhclient[385]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Jun  9 12:10:16 localhost dhclient[385]: Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jun  9 12:10:16 localhost dhclient[385]: All rights reserved.
Jun  9 12:10:16 localhost dhclient[385]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jun  9 12:10:16 localhost dhclient[385]: 
Jun  9 12:10:17 localhost dhclient[385]: Listening on LPF/enp4s0/00:05:b7:e7:38:a7
Jun  9 12:10:17 localhost dhclient[385]: Sending on   LPF/enp4s0/00:05:b7:e7:38:a7
Jun  9 12:10:17 localhost dhclient[385]: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Jun  9 12:10:17 localhost dhclient[385]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.5.57 on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jun  9 12:10:21 localhost dhclient[385]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.5.57 on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jun  9 12:10:31 localhost dhclient[385]: DHCPACK of 192.168.5.57 from 192.168.5.254
Jun  9 12:10:31 localhost dhclient[385]: bound to 192.168.5.57 -- renewal in 41469 seconds.
```

The renewal after the first binding is 32796 seconds (9.11 hours). The request is a one-way broadcast before 9.11 hours. It's around the 4-hour mark.

Is there a connection loss during the process of leasing an IP and the server giving one out?

Comment: That looks like `dhclient` was restarted

Comment: So if the `dhclient` is restarted, why does it initiate a new request for the same IP? Is it because the IP might have been allotted to a different host in the mean time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DHCP clients try to renew their lease before it ends in order prevent lack of service.

The DHCP spec, [RFC-2131](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131), says the client should start trying to renew a lease at 50% of time in case the DHCP server is unreachable so that it has enough time to try several times before the lease expires.

During a renew like this, the host still has the IP address. It does not release the address.

If the host were to wait for the lease to expire before renewing, then there would be a period of time where it has no address and any background transient or ongoing connections would fail until a new negotiation is successfully completed.

Also, when a new lease is acquired, if the old one had expired or been released, the new one might not be the same IP address with all the problems that would bring of it were to happen in the middle of user activity. This allows for a client host to keep the same IP address for as long as it needs of that is longer than the maximum lease time while still preventing stale leases from building up and exhausting the pool.

Comment: What you wrote might be true in general but in this case, I think the host was rebooted. The following lines indicate that as @ikkachu commented on the post.

`Jun  9 12:10:16 localhost dhclient[385]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Jun  9 12:10:16 localhost dhclient[385]: Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jun  9 12:10:16 localhost dhclient[385]: All rights reserved.
Jun  9 12:10:16 localhost dhclient[385]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/ `

Comment: So this was probably a rebind instead of a renew. The differences are explained in the RFC.

Comment: @rocky_alpine It's functionally the same thing, whether a reboot or not as there is only the "DCHPREQUEST" command, no separate renew command. The client will check it's DHCP leases cache and if there is an active one then it will use that to make the new request. The DHCP server cannot tell the difference between a rebooted client and one asking to renew in the middle of a lease.